# Is there a way to schedule two appointments at the same time on different days. when importing the information from an info path form

Tags: infopath

We issue out equipment that must be returned at a latter date I would like to schedule the Pick-up and the Turn-in dates at the same time. Is there a way that I can do so in one scheduling box instead of having to do it twice. I would like to do so while importing from an info path form that I built.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the date auto populated in info path you can use rules. When someone schedules a pickup date a rule cam be created that will add X number of days and auto populate the return date.

If you want these appointments to appear in a separate sharwpoint calendar you should mise workflow. The workflow would run when a new form is submitted and can create appointments in the specified calendar.

Hope this helps.

Tal